# Why is it always returning true?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, boolean

Just doing some exercises from edabit and just couldn't figure out this one.

Prompt: An array is special if every even index contains an even number and every odd index contains an odd number. Create a function that returns true if an array is special, and false otherwise.

```
   function isSpecialArray(arr) {
      for (var i = 0; i <arr.length; i+=2) {
        if ((arr[i] % 2 === 0) && (arr[i+1] % 2 === 1)){
          return true
        }
      }
      return false
    }
```

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 1, 6, 3])) //➞ false

I have returning false outside the for loop but why is it still returning true? Thanks for your help!

Comment: because you exit on the first check.... You should be returning when it is NOT valid.

Comment: not necessarily the first check, just as soon as ANY Even:Odd pair is found in the right position

Answer (score 1):

The if statement where it returns true will return true the first time it runs.

So when you run your code, it's checking arr[0] which is 2.  2 % 2 === 0 (true) and arr[1] is 7, and 7 % 2 === 1 is true.  So it's returning true after running the first time.

You'll need to change this so that it returns true only after it runs through the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because when `i=0` then
`arr[i] = 2` and `arr[i+0] = 7`

and so `2 % 2 === 0` AND `7 % 2 === 1`

which meets the condition and the function exits

```js
function isSpecialArray(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    console.log(arr[i+1]);
    if ((arr[i] % 2 === 0) && (arr[i + 1] % 2 === 1)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log(isSpecialArray([2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 1, 6, 3]));
```